# VB to C# Translation

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

In VB (ASP.NET)

```
Application("myapp")= Server.CreateObject("APP.Engine")

aa = Application("myapp").myMethod(2)
```

works.

In C# I tried

```
Application["myapp"]= Server.CreateObject("APP.Engine")
```

but

```
Application["myapp"].myMethod(2)
```

fails with

```
'object' does not contain a definition for 'myMethod'
```

How can I expose the public interface in C#?

Comment: Hang on, does this mean that VB.NET does a dynamic invocation for every method call on the `System.Object` type? Otherwise, why is no cast necessary in VB.NET here?

Comment: @Timwi: Yes, it does mean that, believe it or not. This is why [extension methods defined on the `Object` type don't behave as most developers expect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402660/why-does-this-extension-method-throw-a-nullreferenceexception-in-vb-net).

Comment: @Timwi only if Option Strict is 'Off', which (unfortunately IMO) is the default

Answer (score 7):

If you have access to the defining type (i.e. not a raw COM object), you can simply cast:

```
((APP.Engine)Application["myapp"]).myMethod(2);
```

If you are using c# 4.0, you can do:

```
dymamic myApp = Application["myapp"];
myApp.myMethod(2);
```

Otherwise you will have to use dynamic method invocation using reflection and `Type.InvokeMember(...)`

Comment: Woah... lets not go flinging around dynamic so lightly.

Comment: @ChaosPandion - For COM calls from c#, dynamic fits the bill quite nicely, I think - hardly lightly.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: COM is where `dynamic` is most useful!

Comment: @Phillip - I agree, but we don't know if the object is a COM object. I think your current answer does provide enough information for the OP to make a well informed choice though.

Comment: @Brian - You may not have seen the original answer which did not provide the same info you see now.

Comment: @ChaosPandion - yes, my hitting of "shift enter" with current greasemonkey scripts did post a poor partial draft.  I'll give you that raw "use dynamic" is not good advice at all.

Comment: @Philip Rieck: Thanks for the solution dynamic myApp = Application["myapp"]; myApp.myMethod(2); Once I corrected the typo & figured how to target framework 4, it worked & works well

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast to the correct class first, like:

```
((APP.Engine)Application["myapp"]).myMethod(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast the result of Application["myapp"] to the correct type, like so:

```
((APP.Engine)Application["myapp"]).myMethod(2);
```

Other options include creating a local reference and using that instead.

Answer (score 0):

This basically happens as C# is strongly typed language. When you call Application you are actually calling a collection of type Object. The collection is actually an array of Object. We take it as object because it will enable you to store almost anything to the collection.

Now Application["myapp"] will eventually return an object of System.Object type.

So you need to typecast the object to your type.

```
App.Engine obj = Application["myapp"] as App.Engine;
if(obj !=  null)
  obj.myMethod(2);
```

The object obj is a reference to the actual type and the compiler will not throw any exception if you call myMethod(2).

Answer (score 0):

Just remember one thing while converting code from `VB` to `C#` is, C# is the *strongly typed language* and before you access any type, you will need to *convert* it. However same wasn't required in VB.

So for this example you would need to use `App.Engine` for type conversion.

```
((APP.Engine)Application["myapp"]).myMethod(2)
```